# No Directive annotation found on (some service)

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

After traveling through angular2's git repository, and after a long search inside stack overflow I need to understand two things.
1)The first one is why I'm having this type of exception, and my .ts files are these:

### DownloadDocuments.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Headers,Http,Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { Result } from '../components/downloads/documents/result'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
@Injectable()
export class DownloadDocumentsService{
    constructor(private http:Http){}
    private url='http://someplace/;
    getResults(): Observable<Result[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }
    private handleError (error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` :'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

and the service is injected into this component

### DocumentsArea.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core'
import { Result } from './documents/result'
import { ResultComponent } from './documents/result.component'
import { DownloadDocumentsService } from '../../services/DownloadDocumentsService.service' 
@Component({
    selector:'documents-download',
    templateUrl:'app/components/downloads/documentsArea.component.html',
    styleUrls:['app/components/downloads/documentsArea.component.css'],
    directives:[ResultComponent,DownloadDocumentService]
})
export class DocumentsAreaComponent implements OnInit{
    documentsList: Result[];
    errore: string;
    private document:Result;
    mode='Observable'
    constructor(private downloadDocumentService: DownloadDocumentService){}
    getDocuments(){
        this.downloadDocumentService.getResults()
            .subscribe(
                documentsList=>this.documentsList=documentsList,
                error => this.errore=<any>error
            )
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        this.getDocuments();
    }
}
```

and the exception that I get is this one

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on DownloadDocumentsService

2)How can I document about the possible exception raised by angular 2? I'm new to angular 2 (as you can see from the code, in fact most part of the .ts files contains the same code given in the developer guide, from the chapter 'HTTP client') but to me the error message that I get is extremely generic (I think), because I understand that it means that the 'DownloadDocumentsService lacks something that makes it a directive'?!? Even if that's not the real meaning of this error, most of the people solved this problem in very different ways, making it clear to me that the I'm not understanding the exception. So what's the real meaning of the error? How can I debug it when I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DownloadDocumentService` service must be specified within the `providers` attribute of your component and not in the `directives` one. The latter is only for directives / components.

Here is a sample:

```
directives: [ResultComponent],
providers: [DownloadDocumentService]
```

To be usable, a class provided in the `directives` attribute needs to have either the `@Directive` or `@Component` decorator to set configuration metadata. Simple classes aren't supported at this level. The `@Injectable` decorator doesn't provide things like that and are "only" to be able to inject dependencies into a class...

Comment: Thanks perfect. So that's the error, i did'nt complitely misunderstood the meaning of the message.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes! I agree with you that error messages can be difficult to understand ;-)